# I want to make a specific query to group specific information about 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

So I have 2 tables that look like this:

```
Factory
| name | timeoperating | operatedpieces |

Pieces
| serial | piecetype | unit (foreign key referencing factory.name) |
```

The "Unit" in "Pieces" is a foreign key that references "Name" in "Factory".
I want to make a query that has "name","timeoperating","operated pieces" and then 9 more columns with how many pieces from each type (from P1 to P9) that have that "unit" or "name" connected. One name per row of course.

I've tried many different things but I never get the query to return anything even similar to what I want, is this even possible?

Output (1st row):

```
| factory.name | factory.timeoperating | factory.operatedpieces |
  count(pieces.piecetype) where piecetype=P1 and unit=factory.name | 
  (then other 8 columns like the last one 
   but with piecetype = Px where X is the column number)
```

Ah I'm scared I didn't make myself clear enough...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Please show us what queries did you try already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that data using 9 "scalar subqueries".

For example:

```
select 
 f.name,
 f.timeoperating,
 f.operatedpieces,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 1) as c1,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 2) as c2,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 3) as c3,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 4) as c4,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 5) as c5,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 6) as c6,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 7) as c7,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 8) as c8,
 (select count(*) from pieces p where p.unit = f.name and p.piecetype = 9) as c9
from factory f
```

Comment: I spent 3 hours browsing on google until I decided to create an account here and ask for help. In less than 5 minutes you spared me other hours of work. I was trying to use the join command for each cell on the table, you gave me a much better solution.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @diogofd8 Glad to be of help.